# I am unable retrieve the data from post request

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to retrieve the data from the post request, but it just not comming.. it went to success page without returning data
Code:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
def page1(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST['input1']
        print(name)
    else:
        return render(request,'add_image/page1.html')
def page2(request):
   return render(request,'add_image/pag2.html')
```

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page1</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/add/page2/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="input1">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page2</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to retrieve the data from post request but it is not comming, I even tried get and cookies method but still not working,

Comment: You are posting the values to page2 but expect the data on page1.